# Powershell collection behavior

Tags: arrays, powershell, collections

Given the following code snippet:

```
$Servers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Server = New-Object System.Object
$Server | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServerName" -Value ""

$Server.ServerName = "Server1"
$Servers.Add($Server) | Out-Null
$Server.ServerName = "Server2"
$Servers.Add($Server)| Out-Null
$Servers
```

I expected it to return:

### ServerName

Server1
Server2

But I get:

### ServerName

Server2
Server2

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: It is how reference types work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PetSerAl said in a comment, it's because it's a reference type. When you add the variable to the arraylist, you're adding a *reference* not the value itself. So when you change the variable, the reference points to the new value.

You should create a new object each time:

```
$Server = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Server = "Server1" }    
$Servers.Add($Server) | Out-Null
$Server = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Server = "Server2" }
$Servers.Add($Server)| Out-Null
$Servers
```

If you don't need the actual object, you could just add the strings directly, which would bypass this whole issue. I assumed that you did need the object though.

You can make a method function to create your custom object type. In PowerShell 5 you could also create your own class, but I'll just show a function here:

```
function New-MyObject {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $Server
)
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Server = $Server }
}
$Servers.Add((New-MyObject -Server "Server1")) | Out-Null
$Servers.Add((New-MyObject -Server "Server2")) | Out-Null
```

Comment: The explanation makes sense.  Thanks for that.

I get a "Method invocation failed because [System.Object] does not contain a method named 'Clone'." error using the posted code.  I presume  $Server should be something other than a System.Object, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @JimG I misunderstand the example slightly, but yes it's true, not every object has a `.Clone()` method. So the question here is, what type of object is `$Server`? How you make a copy of that will depend on what it is.

Comment: $Server is currently a System.Object, which is shown in the original code. 
 
My question is what type of object SHOULD I make $server as  System.Object does not have a clone method.  Really, any way to add a literal and non-reference object to the collection should suffice.